# How to delete file from API using React-Native-Fetch-Blob?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I'm trying to remove the file from the API using **React-Native-Fetch-Blob**, but it doesn't work. However when trying to delete the file using Postman it works.

```
var dataToServer = { 'path' : this.state.path};

RNFetchBlob.fetch('DELETE', 'url', {
        'Authorization' : tokenJSON.access,
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      }, JSON.stringify(dataToServer))
      .uploadProgress((written, total) => {
        console.log('uploaded', written / total)
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with "regular" fetch from [Fetch API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#using-fetch)

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': tokenJSON.access,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
}).then(response =>

);
```